# Matrix Field Conditional

Tags: matrix, conditional, block-types

I'm trying to attach a custom header image for each entry, if none is selected then the default one will be displayed.

1. `contentBuilder` is the Matrix field.
2. `imgHeader` is an assets block type.
3. `img` is the actual field

---

```
{% for content in entry.contentBuilder.type('imgHeader') %}

    {% if content.img|length %}
        {{ content.img.first.url }}
    {% else %}
        default jpg
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

However this doesn't work. Please advise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image are returned as an array so could use either of the following:

`{{ content.img[0].url }}`

Or set a variable which fetches the asset to then output its fields

```
{% set asset = content.img.first() %}
{{ asset.url }}
```

Related: [Looping through images in a Asset field type](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12483/looping-through-images-in-a-asset-field-type)

---

**UPDATE**: The line `{% if content.img|length %}` will always be true because you are checking for existence of the field. You need to instead check that the field has a value using one of the methods below:

```
{% for content in entry.contentBuilder.type('imgHeader') %}

    {% if content.img[0]|length %}
        {{ content.img[0].url }}
    {% else %}
        default jpg
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for content in entry.contentBuilder.type('imgHeader') %}

    {% set image = content.img.first() %}

    {% if image|length %}
        {{ image.url }}
    {% else %}
        default jpg
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, my version does display the image if it was assigned to the field. The problem is that the whole conditional don't work if there is no field added.